# htmlentities() not converting right triangle to HTML entity

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, html-entities

According to this list: http://mcdlr.com/8/, this special character: ▶ has the HTML entity `&#9654;`. Therefore I thought that the PHP function `htmlentities()` would convert input of ▶ to `&#9654;`. However, this is what is shown when I run the string with that special character through that function and store it in an MySQL database:

> â–¶

I have set up the HTTP header on the page from where I send the string to `<meta charset="utf-8">` and I even tried adding this in the PHP file where the string is processed: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`, but it doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your database table's collation?

Comment: @Mike `latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: That's your problem. Change it to utf8_general_ci.

Comment: @Mike hmm.. Changed collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` but still get `â–¶` in the DB. Could there be something else needed for this to work?

Comment: Did you insert the value again? If not, you need to do that. You inserted a UTF-8 value into an ISO-8859-1 table. There's no way to convert that back into UTF-8 and have the extra characters show up how you want them to.

Comment: Yes, I have tried inserting the value multiple times after the change. Even if I cut down the code to just the SQL-query, I get the same result as before. The PHP code: `require('connect.php');
$send = $dbc->prepare('INSERT INTO bands (band) VALUES (:band)');
$send->execute(array(':band' => htmlentities('▶')));` and a picture of the DB: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2cggdjc.jpg

Comment: @Mike it's all working with strings like `"some text"` (which gives `&quot;some text&quot;`). But with this right triangle special character it still just doesn't :/

Comment: It works with double quotes because they are also a part of ISO-8859-1. Another question, where does the `▶` come from? Is it hard-coded into the PHP script, or does it come from the browser?

Comment: @Mike It comes from the browser (user input, just a regular text field. The value gets sent with jQuery to a php page for storage).

Comment: I think I must have somehow overlooked the part about you using htmlentities. If you are using htmlentities on it *before* it goes into the DB, there should be no issues. Try doing `var_dump` of the exact string that goes into the database.

Comment: @Mike `var_dump`-ed the string that were to be put in the DB. It says: `string(3) "▶"`. BTW big thanks to you for your patience :)

Comment: Are you seeing `â–¶` in phpMyAdmin too?

Comment: Also, are you passing a character encoding to the PDO constructor?

Comment: @Mike yes, like this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/ifzte0.jpg

Comment: @Mike I don't think so, the PDO code I showed is the only PDO code used there. That actually may be it.How do you pass character encoding?

Comment: Please show the line that would be something like `$dbc = new PDO( ... );`. Probably in connect.php. Don't paste your password though.

Comment: `$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', '******', '*****');`

Comment: Change the first parameter to: `'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****;charset=utf8;'` and try again.

Comment: NP. I'll write it up into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with UTF-8 characters, the key is that every encoding needs to be in UTF-8 or else it will be converted to ISO-8859-1.

Make sure you check:

- The collation of the table column in the database
- If the value is hard-coded into the PHP file, make sure the file is saved in UTF-8 format
- If the data comes from the browser, make sure the PHP Content-Type header is for UTF-8 encoding. Typically you can leave out the `<meta charset>` in the HTML since browsers will use the HTTP header if it is received.
- The connection to the database must specify the encoding, like this:

.

```
$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****;charset=utf8;', '******', '*****');
```

**Edit:**

I think the [htmlentities manual page](http://php.net/htmlentities) might be a bit misleading:

> htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

I think it should say, "Convert all applicable characters **available in the translation table** to HTML entities". Not all characters are necessarily available in the translation table, and anything not there will not be converted into their HTML entities. To view which characters are in your translation table, see [get_html_translation_table()](http://php.net/get_html_translation_table).

For example, doing:

```
print_r( get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES));
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    ["] => &quot;
    [&] => &amp;
    [<] => &lt;
    [>] => &gt;
    [ ] => &nbsp;
    [¡] => &iexcl;
    [¢] => &cent;
    [£] => &pound;
    [¤] => &curren;
    [¥] => &yen;
    [¦] => &brvbar;
    [§] => &sect;
    [¨] => &uml;
    [©] => &copy;
    [ª] => &ordf;
    [«] => &laquo;
    [¬] => &not;
    [­] => &shy;
    [®] => &reg;
    [¯] => &macr;
    [°] => &deg;
    [±] => &plusmn;
    [²] => &sup2;
    [³] => &sup3;
    [´] => &acute;
    [µ] => &micro;
    [¶] => &para;
    [·] => &middot;
    [¸] => &cedil;
    [¹] => &sup1;
    [º] => &ordm;
    [»] => &raquo;
    [¼] => &frac14;
    [½] => &frac12;
    [¾] => &frac34;
    [¿] => &iquest;
    [À] => &Agrave;
    [Á] => &Aacute;
    [Â] => &Acirc;
    [Ã] => &Atilde;
    [Ä] => &Auml;
    [Å] => &Aring;
    [Æ] => &AElig;
    [Ç] => &Ccedil;
    [È] => &Egrave;
    [É] => &Eacute;
    [Ê] => &Ecirc;
    [Ë] => &Euml;
    [Ì] => &Igrave;
    [Í] => &Iacute;
    [Î] => &Icirc;
    [Ï] => &Iuml;
    [Ð] => &ETH;
    [Ñ] => &Ntilde;
    [Ò] => &Ograve;
    [Ó] => &Oacute;
    [Ô] => &Ocirc;
    [Õ] => &Otilde;
    [Ö] => &Ouml;
    [×] => &times;
    [Ø] => &Oslash;
    [Ù] => &Ugrave;
    [Ú] => &Uacute;
    [Û] => &Ucirc;
    [Ü] => &Uuml;
    [Ý] => &Yacute;
    [Þ] => &THORN;
    [ß] => &szlig;
    [à] => &agrave;
    [á] => &aacute;
    [â] => &acirc;
    [ã] => &atilde;
    [ä] => &auml;
    [å] => &aring;
    [æ] => &aelig;
    [ç] => &ccedil;
    [è] => &egrave;
    [é] => &eacute;
    [ê] => &ecirc;
    [ë] => &euml;
    [ì] => &igrave;
    [í] => &iacute;
    [î] => &icirc;
    [ï] => &iuml;
    [ð] => &eth;
    [ñ] => &ntilde;
    [ò] => &ograve;
    [ó] => &oacute;
    [ô] => &ocirc;
    [õ] => &otilde;
    [ö] => &ouml;
    [÷] => &divide;
    [ø] => &oslash;
    [ù] => &ugrave;
    [ú] => &uacute;
    [û] => &ucirc;
    [ü] => &uuml;
    [ý] => &yacute;
    [þ] => &thorn;
    [ÿ] => &yuml;
    [Œ] => &OElig;
    [œ] => &oelig;
    [Š] => &Scaron;
    [š] => &scaron;
    [Ÿ] => &Yuml;
    [ƒ] => &fnof;
    [ˆ] => &circ;
    [˜] => &tilde;
    [Α] => &Alpha;
    [Β] => &Beta;
    [Γ] => &Gamma;
    [Δ] => &Delta;
    [Ε] => &Epsilon;
    [Ζ] => &Zeta;
    [Η] => &Eta;
    [Θ] => &Theta;
    [Ι] => &Iota;
    [Κ] => &Kappa;
    [Λ] => &Lambda;
    [Μ] => &Mu;
    [Ν] => &Nu;
    [Ξ] => &Xi;
    [Ο] => &Omicron;
    [Π] => &Pi;
    [Ρ] => &Rho;
    [Σ] => &Sigma;
    [Τ] => &Tau;
    [Υ] => &Upsilon;
    [Φ] => &Phi;
    [Χ] => &Chi;
    [Ψ] => &Psi;
    [Ω] => &Omega;
    [α] => &alpha;
    [β] => &beta;
    [γ] => &gamma;
    [δ] => &delta;
    [ε] => &epsilon;
    [ζ] => &zeta;
    [η] => &eta;
    [θ] => &theta;
    [ι] => &iota;
    [κ] => &kappa;
    [λ] => &lambda;
    [μ] => &mu;
    [ν] => &nu;
    [ξ] => &xi;
    [ο] => &omicron;
    [π] => &pi;
    [ρ] => &rho;
    [ς] => &sigmaf;
    [σ] => &sigma;
    [τ] => &tau;
    [υ] => &upsilon;
    [φ] => &phi;
    [χ] => &chi;
    [ψ] => &psi;
    [ω] => &omega;
    [ϑ] => &thetasym;
    [ϒ] => &upsih;
    [ϖ] => &piv;
    [ ] => &ensp;
    [ ] => &emsp;
    [ ] => &thinsp;
    [‌] => &zwnj;
    [‍] => &zwj;
    [‎] => &lrm;
    [‏] => &rlm;
    [–] => &ndash;
    [—] => &mdash;
    [‘] => &lsquo;
    [’] => &rsquo;
    [‚] => &sbquo;
    [“] => &ldquo;
    [”] => &rdquo;
    [„] => &bdquo;
    [†] => &dagger;
    [‡] => &Dagger;
    [•] => &bull;
    […] => &hellip;
    [‰] => &permil;
    [′] => &prime;
    [″] => &Prime;
    [‹] => &lsaquo;
    [›] => &rsaquo;
    [‾] => &oline;
    [⁄] => &frasl;
    [€] => &euro;
    [ℑ] => &image;
    [℘] => &weierp;
    [ℜ] => &real;
    [™] => &trade;
    [ℵ] => &alefsym;
    [←] => &larr;
    [↑] => &uarr;
    [→] => &rarr;
    [↓] => &darr;
    [↔] => &harr;
    [↵] => &crarr;
    [⇐] => &lArr;
    [⇑] => &uArr;
    [⇒] => &rArr;
    [⇓] => &dArr;
    [⇔] => &hArr;
    [∀] => &forall;
    [∂] => &part;
    [∃] => &exist;
    [∅] => &empty;
    [∇] => &nabla;
    [∈] => &isin;
    [∉] => &notin;
    [∋] => &ni;
    [∏] => &prod;
    [∑] => &sum;
    [−] => &minus;
    [∗] => &lowast;
    [√] => &radic;
    [∝] => &prop;
    [∞] => &infin;
    [∠] => &ang;
    [∧] => &and;
    [∨] => &or;
    [∩] => &cap;
    [∪] => &cup;
    [∫] => &int;
    [∴] => &there4;
    [∼] => &sim;
    [≅] => &cong;
    [≈] => &asymp;
    [≠] => &ne;
    [≡] => &equiv;
    [≤] => &le;
    [≥] => &ge;
    [⊂] => &sub;
    [⊃] => &sup;
    [⊄] => &nsub;
    [⊆] => &sube;
    [⊇] => &supe;
    [⊕] => &oplus;
    [⊗] => &otimes;
    [⊥] => &perp;
    [⋅] => &sdot;
    [⌈] => &lceil;
    [⌉] => &rceil;
    [⌊] => &lfloor;
    [⌋] => &rfloor;
    [〈] => &lang;
    [〉] => &rang;
    [◊] => &loz;
    [♠] => &spades;
    [♣] => &clubs;
    [♥] => &hearts;
    [♦] => &diams;
)
```

So any characters not listed above will not be converted to their entities. Note, if you set the `ENT_HTML5` flag, the translation table will be about 10 times larger, however it still does not contain (at least on my server) the entity for `▶`. It only has named entities.

If you need to convert all characters to their respective entities, you can use the following function (Disclaimer, I did not write it. Here is the original source: http://php.net/htmlentities#107985):

```
// Unicode-proof htmlentities.
// Returns 'normal' chars as chars and weirdos as numeric html entites.
function superentities( $str ){
    // get rid of existing entities else double-escape
    $str = html_entity_decode(stripslashes($str),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    $ar = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $str );  // return array of every multi-byte character
    foreach ($ar as $c){
        $o = ord($c);
        if ( (strlen($c) > 1) || /* multi-byte [unicode] */
            ($o <32 || $o > 126) || /* <- control / latin weirdos -> */
            ($o >33 && $o < 40) ||/* quotes + ambersand */
            ($o >59 && $o < 63) /* html */
        ) {
            // convert to numeric entity
            $c = mb_encode_numericentity($c,array (0x0, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');
        }
        $str2 .= $c;
    }
    return $str2;
}
```

So using the example `▶`, you can do:

```
var_dump(superentities('▶')); // outputs string(7) "&#9654;"
```

However, with all that said, I would recommend that you store everything in your database *without* encoding it. Typically it is preferred to encode appropriately before outputting to the browser. That way if you ever need to change the way you encode it, you won't have to decode it and re-encode it in some other way. To do that, you will have to make sure all of the encodings are correctly set to UTF-8 as mentioned in my original answer.

Comment: I'm still confused about one thing though. I don't know why the htmlentities function isn't working. It should be converting it to `&#9654;` as you mentioned in your question. If it were converting it, you wouldn't have this issue. So maybe my answer isn't actually correct, because I *think* you're storing it as `▶` in the database instead of `&#9654;`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I took a look now you mentioned it and there's `▶` and not the entity code in the DB. It's very strange indeed, because as I mentioned earlier the function works just fine on some strings like quotes, £, etc.

Comment: Could it possible be that `htmlentities()` does not affect `▶`? For example, that special character is not in this list (http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) which claims to be the complete list of HTML entities.

Comment: What result does a run through `htmlentities()` for `▶` give you?

Comment: I get the same result as you. It doesn't convert it. However the link above is definitely NOT a complete list of UTF-8 characters. Not even close.

Comment: `htmlentities()` accept three parameters, so perhaps the two other parameters need to be altered for it to work...?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be encoding any non-ASCII characters for me for some reason.

Comment: Should it? As I'm looking at lists of html entities, `▶` can not be found.. Really confused right now :S

Comment: Found anything that could explain this?

Comment: Now it all makes sense. Thanks for all your help, Mike. I will follow your tip and encode it right before browser output. You deserve an upvote too but I unfortunately have to few reps to do that right now. Will do when I get there, though :). Cheers and thanks again!